Constraintlayout in LinearLayout in ScrollView
i am trying to display a listing in three columns in my layout.
Since I put the headings and the recyclerviews into a constraint layout my code crashes.
In the design interface it also seems that my constraint layout would be endless.
I am currently teaching myself coding and have the feeling that I have written myself into a dead end.
It would be very nice if someone could tell me if the code is correct so that I can look elsewhere, or if this is a frankestein monster that will stay dead forever
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Eingabefeld für Rule-set Namen -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/ruleSetNameEditText"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Eigende Regeln 1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/deleteRuleSetButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_24dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/editRuleSetButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_edit_24dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Optionen -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- TextView für Optionen -->
            <TextView
                android:text="Optionen"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"/>

            <!-- Horizontaler Container für Checkbox und Button -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <!-- Checkbox für Freies Einstellen -->
                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/freeSettingCheckBox"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Freies Einstellen" />

                <!-- Button für Erweiterte Einstellungen -->
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/advancedSettingsButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Erweiterte Einstellungen"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Eingabefeld für Anzahl der Spieler -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:text="Anzahl der Spieler "
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/playerCountEditText"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_background" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Anzeige der Anzahl Dorfbewohner -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:text="Dorfbewohner"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/villagerCountTextView"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/readtext_background" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Headrer für die karten , sollen alle nebeneinander sein -->

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/block1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/block2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Karten"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_cards"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/block2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/block1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/block3"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Anzahl"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_countCards"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/block3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/block2"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:baselineAligned="false"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Spieler"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_StandardPlayers"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


        <!-- Abbrechen und Speichern Buttons -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Abbrechen" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/saveButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Speichern" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

at the beginning i had a simple recyclerview that listed information and items in a defined area under my header. Everything worked without a hitch.
Then I thought I would like the headers I have to dynamically adapt to the items in the recyclerview so that they are always centered above it.
so i tried to put each heading in a block and each heading in its block in its own recyclerview so that heading and content always fit together.
Unfortunately, since then I always get a crash when I try to call the class
if you are interested here is my old code that worked
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Eingabefeld für Rule-set Namen -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/ruleSetNameEditText"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Eigende Regeln 1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/deleteRuleSetButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_24dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/editRuleSetButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_edit_24dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Optionen -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- TextView für Optionen -->
        <TextView
            android:text="Optionen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"/>

        <!-- Horizontaler Container für Checkbox und Button -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <!-- Checkbox für Freies Einstellen -->
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/freeSettingCheckBox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Freies Einstellen" />

            <!-- Button für Erweiterte Einstellungen -->
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/advancedSettingsButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Erweiterte Einstellungen"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Eingabefeld für Anzahl der Spieler -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:text="Anzahl der Spieler "
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/playerCountEditText"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_background" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Anzeige der Anzahl Dorfbewohner -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:text="Dorfbewohner"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/villagerCountTextView"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/readtext_background" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <!-- Kartenbereich -->
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/cardsRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



        <!-- Abbrechen und Speichern Buttons -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Abbrechen" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/saveButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Speichern" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

In any layout don't give dependable constrain as box2 start at box1 end and end at box 3 start now in box3 you give start at box2 end don't give it instead use width percentage I have given in below use it.
use this line for more easy way
app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".33"

here is detailed code
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="8dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Eingabefeld für Rule-set Namen -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ruleSetNameEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Eigende Regeln 1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/deleteRuleSetButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/editRuleSetButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Optionen -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- TextView für Optionen -->
        <TextView
            android:text="Optionen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"/>

        <!-- Horizontaler Container für Checkbox und Button -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <!-- Checkbox für Freies Einstellen -->
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/freeSettingCheckBox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Freies Einstellen" />

            <!-- Button für Erweiterte Einstellungen -->
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/advancedSettingsButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Erweiterte Einstellungen"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Eingabefeld für Anzahl der Spieler -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:text="Anzahl der Spieler "
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/playerCountEditText"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Anzeige der Anzahl Dorfbewohner -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:text="Dorfbewohner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/villagerCountTextView"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Headrer für die karten , sollen alle nebeneinander sein -->

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/block1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".33"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Karten"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_cards"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/block2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/block1"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".33"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Anzahl"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_countCards"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/block3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".33"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Spieler"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_StandardPlayers"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    <!-- Abbrechen und Speichern Buttons -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Abbrechen" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Speichern" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

